# How to authenticate WSO2IS User management APIs without password in Java

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-cloud, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2IS 5.3.0 to authenticate my application. I have a GUI to get Username and Password to authenticate. 
Once it is authenticated, I am using PAC4J to store and retrieve user profile. It is using SAML SSO.

Now I want to get all the users in my tenant through WSO2IS Web API and list it in my application
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-listUsers()

Since application is already authenticated, I can't get password again to authenticate the stub like this `authenticationAdminStub.login(userName, password, remoteIp)` to get user list.

I have commonAuthId and samlssoTokenId cookies and WSO2Carbon certificates. What are the other ways to authenticate stub without password and  get user list.

Answer (score 2):

Please mention which authentication protocol you are using in first step since you mention about collecting username and password to your own GUI.
However you can achieve the requirement by exchanging SAML response to admin cookie by using **SAML2SSOAuthenticationService**.
Please find[1] for more information.

[1] http://firzhanblogger.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-get-session-cookie-from-webapp.html

Comment: This is working good. But I am using PAC4j and I could not get SAMLResponse. I am getting JSESSIONID from the cookies but I can't login through that JSESSIONID